# TDengine monitoring functions

Tags: monitoring, tdengine

Does TDengine provide functions of monitoring it own system? For example, users could use a way to check on cluster health status, file system usage, I/O usage etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a 'log' database from TDengine to find such information or use grafana plugin to monitor them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Grafana to monitoring the TDengine database with [TDinsight](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/15167).